# How to addslashes automatically using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, addslashes

I want to apply addslashes() to all the post elements got through

$this->input->post('my_var');

How can I do that ? Is there any feature like filters under wordpress for this ?

Comment: because I already tried to find the solution as the slashes are not getting added automatically. and many people suggested to use Active Records method. But I have executed select query using this->db->query() in the whole project all over places. And it will take weeks to change all to active records. so I through to this solution if it is possible.

Comment: Addslash can not prevent sql injection. It is even worse than mysql_real_escape_string. You need to use placeholders.

Comment: As for solution to your problem, you have two option. Use query builder or use placeholders.... no other way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something global. My idea is to edit the global post function in the codeigniter to use addslashes on everything. You can find that function in:

**/yourfolder/system/core/Input.php**

You can escape it by setting it global.

```
function post($index = NULL, $xss_clean = FALSE)
    {
        // Check if a field has been provided
        if ($index === NULL AND ! empty($_POST))
        {
            $post = array();

            // Loop through the full _POST array and return it
            foreach (array_keys($_POST) as $key)
            {
                $post[$key] = addslashes($this->_fetch_from_array($_POST, $key, $xss_clean));
            }
            return $post;
        }

        return addslashes($this->_fetch_from_array($_POST, $index, $xss_clean));
    }
```

Although I don't really find it as good solution to modify the global functions this should do the trick in your case.

Edit: I see that input->post **already does that** and you would not need to add that function additionally.